# HTML content overflow when using [innerHTML] in IONIC

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework

Initially I am trying to render dynamic HTML code from a database in ionic, at the moment it does however the content is overflowing and I have not been able in any way to adapt to the framework where I have it. The idea is that for no reason it does not matter the code that exists overflows to avoid being cut.

```
 <div class="ion-padding contentEmail" [innerHTML]="email?.PartMenssage">
  </div>
```

[illustrative image of how it overflows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6eDv.png)

Now although I could place a frame as you can see the error continues to pass, following the css code that I use

```
.contentEmail {
  word-break : break-word;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 5px #bbbbc7;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Mitch, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Intenta publicar en inglés, para que puedan entenderte o puedes intentar publicar en https://es.stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el consejo. Publicaré en inglés